# Querying most popular row

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Basically trying to plan out logic for my query that will count the number of times each time a certain row is used (I dont need the number of times or anything I just need it to Order By the products with mostly used row values.)

Example:

I have a purchases
The purchases table has a row called 'product_id'
I am trying to now query this table, find how many times the SAME product_id is used, and then order the query by the highest amount of times a product_id is used.

I have tried a few things but I am a little lost on the actual logic, so I completely understand that what I have tried doesn't work (doesn't make sense in my head, but I had to try some things).

```
        var grabProducts = db.fixed_purchases.GroupBy(fp => fp.product_id)
            .Select(fp => new fixed_purchases
            {
                Count = fp.Count()
            }).ToList();
```

The best I could do right now. Again, the logic is where I am lost. I don't necessarily need the answer but the logic would do just fine.

I am using ASP C# Linq, but it doesn't matter at all considering this is a SQL question, so please don't look at the Linq, I just wanted to at least post the code I am trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need an `OrderBy` clause after the `GroupBy` to sort the groups based on their count:

```
var grabProducts = db.fixed_purchases
               .GroupBy(fp => fp.product_id)
               .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());
```

Then if you want to get products id's sorted in descending order, you can add a `Select`:

```
var grabProducts = db.fixed_purchases
               .GroupBy(fp => fp.product_id)
               .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
               .Select(g => g.Key)  
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Ah.. I feel stupid, didn't know I could OrderBy(Count()). Thanks, appreciate it.